# How to call image in js from pub/media in magento 2.4

Tags: javascript, magento2.4, pub

i want to call image in js from pub/media, if i'm using this code it will call image from pub/static not pub/media.

```
$("."+keypay).prepend('<img data-bind="attr: { src: require.toUrl('+ "'" + imgPath + "'" +') }" width="45px" />');
```

Comment: it would be easiest to provide url via php - add it in phtml and read in js

Comment: can you show me please, how to do that?

Comment: edit your question and add path of file where you are putting the line above / part of code before / after it, then I'll guide you on it based on what the file is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

> window.checkout.baseUrl + "pub/media" + imgPath

Comment: thank you for your answer :)